# Terminal: “Invalid Argument: dirname” (El Capitan)

Tags: terminal, macos, bash

I noticed the issue when I first went to run

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

in OS X Terminal (10.11.2) but this was returned

```
bash: /usr/bin/defaults: Invalid argument
```

I'm not sure what is going on with defaults, but I also have a similar issue with brew:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/bin/dirname: Invalid argument
```

I clearly broke something (or perhaps malware), but not sure how I did it or when it happened. This is causing all sorts of issues. Any thoughts on fixing it?

My PATH variable looks like this:

```
/Users/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin
```

EDIT:
I noticed my issue is similar to this one: [OS X Yosemite Hard Disk Errors even after Repairing them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158528/os-x-yosemite-hard-disk-errors-even-after-repairing-them) but there's no resolution.

Comment: Please add your PATH (`echo $PATH`) and check your history file and `env`

Comment: $PATH included above.

Comment: What is your prompt? also try with a minimal path - i.e. remove PATH from your .bas* files

Comment: How do I go about removing PATH from my .bas* files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! I reinstalled El Capitan from the recovery partition (hold command-R while restarting). The errors are now gone.